# I want achieve an effect with jquery animate and absolute position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, absolute

In a div I have a two same size images full it,

```
<img id="second image">
<img id="first image">
```

the effect is :

1.the already showed image(first image) collapse with bottom fixed,the second image roll down with top fixed
2.then I insert first image before second image in code,with css position changed,just like above

the first step done well,but the second step doesn't work

[the code and example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/pd43e/2/)

please help me ,thank you

Comment: If I change the file you can see the changes? if yes take a look and tell if this is what you want

Comment: @Hadas:you can change the file ,but you should press the update button in the menu,or create another file ,it needn't login

Comment: Is the Alaa Badran's answer good for you? You want the animation will be like a circle? and continue all the time?

Comment: @Hadas: just I say to him ,his answer is not is my asked,yes,I want a circle,after this,I want use setinterval function to achieve what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update for what you want, hope this works as you exactly want:

```
var stimer;
var updown = true;
$(function () {
    function circling(){
        if(updown === true){
               $('#up').css('top',0).animate({ height: "59px" }, 1000);
            $('#down').css('top',0).animate({ height: 0, top:'59px' }, 1000);
               updown = false;
           } else {
               $('#up').animate({ height: "0",top:'59px' }, 1000);
               $('#down').css('top',0).animate({ height: '59px' }, 1000);
               updown = true;
           }
    }
    stimer = setInterval(function (){circling();}, 2000);
});
```

also add this to css

```
h1{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
I updated 2 lines
1) $('#down').css({ top: "0" });
to be 
$('#down').css({ top: "59px" });
while this box should be at this location when its collapsed.

2) The line: 
$('#down').animate({ height: "59px",'top':'0' }, { duration: 1000 });
to animate the 'top' attribute to go up.

Here is the code how it should look like:

```
        $(function () {
        function x() {
                $('#down').insertBefore('#up');
                // The line was update
                $('#down').css({ top: "59px" });
                $('#up').css({ bottom: "0" });
            // Also this line was updated.
            $('#down').animate({ height: "59px",'top':'0' }, { duration: 1000 });
                $('#up').animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });

        }

        $('#down').animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
        $('#up').animate({ height: "59px" }, { duration: 1000, complete: x });
    });
```

Comment: no,what I want is :the yellow down in the second round,it should from the red's top,not from the bottom

Comment: :no no no,it still doesn't what I want,it more futher……

Comment: the yellow one still rise from the bottom,I want it down from the top

Answer (score 0):

Use this changes:

```
css:
 #up{ background:red;}        
 #down{ background:yellow;}
.top{ height:0px; top:0px; }
.bottom{ height:59px; bottom:0px;}
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    function x() {
        $('h1').last().insertBefore($('h1').first());

        $('h1').first().removeClass();
        $('h1').first().addClass("top");
        $('h1').last().removeClass();
        $('h1').last().addClass("bottom");

        $('h1').first().animate({ height: "59px"}, { duration: 1000});
        $('h1').last().animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000,complete:x });


    }
    $('#down').addClass('bottom');
    $('#up').addClass('top');
    $('#down').animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
    $('#up').animate({ height: "59px" }, { duration: 1000, complete: x });
});
```